# Flutter universal link direct open in app

Tags: flutter, ios-universal-links

I implemented the idea of universal links in flutter, And I used this [article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links) .. and everything works fine

But when click on the link directly opens in the app.

**Is there a way to ask the user first if he wants to open it in the app or browser?**